# Multiple text formats in a qgis label

Tags: qgis, labeling, format

Is there any way to have multiple text formats in a single qgis label?  I am making a map that shows mountain summits.  Many of these summits have more than one name and I would like to show each name in a label and have each name rendered with different formatting to show what type the name is.

For example, summits, in the US, often have an "official" name from the GNIS database, a name as shown on a 1:24000 USGS topo map (often just the elevation of the summit), and a local nickname.  I would like to be able to have a label that renders each name in a different type font and/or font size.

Comment: If you want to do more than just concatenate the different names - different fonts, etc - then you'll need to add the layer twice, and label each one differently. The second copy of the layer can be with no style so only the labels appear.

Comment: @Micha: Conside converting your comment to an answer!

Comment: I tried adding the layer twice, but the result is messy.  The two labels for each summit don't get placed consistently in relation to each other.  Perhaps to get what I want it would be necessary to be able to embed some sort of markup language in the label text.

Comment: You can displace the labels in the Layer tab of the properties window. So shifting the labels of one of the layers a bit in the +x direction, and the other in the -x direction might get you something usable.

Comment: I need to have the labels have some uniformity in their appearance.  Some of them will have three different sub-labels, and it would look very messy if the label placing logic treated them independently from each other, especially as they will be in the vicinity of numerous contour line labels.